Universal $C^*$ -algebra generated by a unital element.
Can someone explain to me how the universal $C^*$ -algebra on one unitary generator is isomorphic to the algebra of continuous functions on $S^1$ ?
I guess I don’t really understand the intuition behind the construction of $C^*$ -algebras on a set of generators and relations in general.
The Wikipedia article doesn’t help this issue for me.
Thanks in advance for your help.

(All $C^{\ast}$-algebras below are unital although I don't think this matters too much.)
I don't know good notation for this $C^{\ast}$-algebra but let's call it $\mathbb{C}[u]$. By definition, $\mathbb{C}[u]$ has the property that morphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{C}[u] \to A$ to another $C^{\ast}$-algebra are in natural bijection with unitary elements $\varphi(u) \in A$ of $A$. If we take $A = C(X, \mathbb{C})$ to be commutative, this tells us that morphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{C}[u] \to A$ are in natural bijection with unitary functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$, which are exactly functions $X \to S^1$.
But there's another $C^{\ast}$-algebra that has this property, namely the $C^{\ast}$-algebra $C(S^1, \mathbb{C})$, by Gelfand duality. And $\mathbb{C}[u]$ is commutative (because it is generated by a single normal element). So the two must be isomorphic by the Yoneda lemma.
In terms of universal elements what this is saying is that the identity function $u : S^1 \to S^1$ is the "universal unitary element." If $v \in A$ is any unitary element of any $C^{\ast}$-algebra then the corresponding homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[u] \to A$ sending $u$ to $v$ can be constructed using the continuous functional calculus applied to $v$.
Similar arguments can prove things like: there is a universal $C^{\ast}$-algebra on a self-adjoint element of norm $\le r$, which is given by $C([-r, r], \mathbb{C})$, or a universal $C^{\ast}$-algebra on a normal element of norm $\le r$, which is given by $C(D_r, \mathbb{C})$ where $D_r = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le r \}$ is the closed disk of radius $r$. However, there is no such universal $C^{\ast}$-algebra without a norm condition.

Thank you for this clear answer.
